# Shuffled file listing in rtorrent

Tags: bittorrent, rtorrent

I've encountered plenty of *.torrent files, in which file names are shuffled, i.e.
*.torrent file contains following directory structure

```
\ Directory 1
 \ SubDir 1.1
  | File1.1.1
  | File1.1.2
 /
 \ SubDir 1.2
  | File 1.2.1
 /
/
\ Directory 2
 \ Subdir 2.1
  | File2.1.1
 /
/
```

(here I try to mimic rtorrent's way to show file list).

The problem is that in rtorrent this file list looks something like this:

```
\ Directory 1
 \ SubDir 1.1
  | File1.1.1
 /
/
\ Directory 2
 \ Subdir 2.1
  | File2.1.1
 /
/    
\ Directory 1
 \ SubDir 1.1
  | File1.1.2
 /
 \ SubDir 1.2
  | File 1.2.1
 /
/
```

Have anyone else come across the same problem?
Is there a name or description for it?
Maybe there is even fix for it (:.

Because I've no success in searching for it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not a rtorrent user, but it looks like it lists the files in the same order they appear in the .torrent file.  
The file list in a .torrent file can be in any arbitrary order. Often they are sorted by size and not the path way / file name.

Comment: @Encombe Good point. I will look into this.